# React and Node Load More Button with Redux State

Tags: node.js, reactjs, axios, fetch-api

Inside **ProductList.jsx** file:

```
    useEffect(() => {
    setFilterProduct(products);
  }, [products]);
  useEffect(() => {
    const data = {
      skip: Skip,
      limit: Limit,
    };
    dispatch(fetchNewProducts(data));
  }, []);

  const handleLoadMore = () => {
   let skip = Skip + Limit;
   console.log(skip);
   const data = {
   skip: skip,
   limit: Limit,
  };
  dispatch(fetchNewProducts(data));
 };
```

BACKEND CODE:

```
const { skip, limit } = req.body;
    console.log(skip, limit);
    let products = await Product.find()
      .populate("category")
      .skip(skip)
      .limit(limit);

    let productsLength = await Product.find().countDocuments();
```

In Redux Action file:

```
const res = await axios.post(
  `${process.env.REACT_APP_API_ENDPOINT}/public/fetch-product`,
  data,
  config
);
dispatch({
  type: "PRODUCT_FETCH",
  payload: res.data,
});
```

In Redux Reducer:

```
case "PRODUCT_FETCH":
          return {
            ...state,
            products: payload.data,
            originalItems: payload.data,
          };
```

Here I'm facing two issues,

1. On first load and second load data is coming properly, but old data are not visible(Only new fetched data are listing). So in reducer I tried to
   `case "PRODUCT_FETCH": return { ...state, products: [...state.products, payload.data], originalItems: [...state.products, payload.data], };`
   But here throws an error, **TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined**
2. After second fetching it's not fetching more data, only the last fetched data are showing again.
   The bug here was limit skip is not incrementing